Is there a way to filter django submodel dropdowns to only appear for the current user?
I have a main model named Event. This event has a submodel named Pogram, and the Program model has a submodel called DetailedProgram.
I have been able to filter the app to make sure that only the logged in user can post for themself. Also, I have managed to make the user only access Events created by the loged in user.
However, I am struggling to find a way to make the user logged in only access the submodel Program's objects as all the object's are being displayed.
Please advise.
I tried using the very filter (user filter) used on the Program model but to no avail

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
